# WinRT Binding data of ViewMode inside a DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-runtime

I wanted to bind data inside a DataTemplate that is stored in ViewModel. I've tried several ways but did not succeed and the solutions for WPF doesn't seems to work on WinRT like AncestorType Property of RelativeSource.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.names}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:mydatatype">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <!--Here I want a TextBlock to show the number-->
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Number = 42;
    public List<mydatatype> names = new List<mydatatype>();
    public ViewModel()
    {
        names.Add(new mydatatype("name1"));
        names.Add(new mydatatype("name2"));
    }
}

public class mydatatype
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public mydatatype(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more code. Because now it's not enough information. For example I don't see "Name" in you ViewModel

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070705/with-compiled-bindings-xbind-why-do-i-have-to-call-bindings-update

Comment: @AlexejSommer I've updated the ViewModel, Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @NotAGenie I've checked the link you've posted. My problem is not that the binding is not updating, I'm trying to bind it to local variable that is available at compile time so there is there is not that problem. What I'm trying to figure out that how to bind data to a property inside a DataTemplate that can't be found in DataType of DataTemplate (binding to _Number_ that isn't in _names_ in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the DataTemplate of other objects by giving them a name and then referencing this. Using this technique you should be able to access its DataContext to bind to the viewmodel directly, even from within a DataTemplate

```
<Page x:Name="PageRoot">
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="MainPanel">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.names}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:mydatatype">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, ElementName=PageRoot}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Not at a computer I can test this on right now so it might not be perfect, but give it a try and then I should be able to edit it later

Comment: I've tried several combinations but it doesn't seems to work. Can you guide me to some resources from where I can learn all these binding related stuff specially for UWP.

Comment: @NickThomsan I updated the example, try using the ElementName to direct the property to look at the same x:Name you set your base Page element to. In terms of reading I'd recommend looking up Jerry Nixon