# Changing Visibility with x:Bind not updating with MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, converters, visibility

Since the Anniversary Update (Build 14383 / 14393) you should be able to [toggle the visibility of XAML elements](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34846.uwp-compiled-binding-windows-10-anniversary-update.aspx) without using a converter, like this:

> ```
> <TextBlock Text="I'm not visible!" Visibility="{x:Bind IsVisibleFalse}" />
> <TextBlock Text="I'm visible!" Visibility="{x:Bind IsVisibleTrue}" />
> ```

I was trying this in my project, minimum target version set to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition. Unfortunately I did not get it to work.

This code works just fine:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsUnlocked, 
    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

This one doesn't (no error on compile, just does not show up when the bool value changes):

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsUnlocked}>
```

I suspect the Mode="TwoWay" to be the issue, as you can't set it "when the binding expression ends with a cast". This code does not work as well:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsUnlocked,
   Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}>
```

So my question is: Am I misssing something or is this not working yet in a MVVM-Scenario and only with code-behind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `Mode` is `OneTime`, which renders your code not working. I suggest you use `OneWay`, which should be usable upon casting.

Comment: this question has a more detailed answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070705/with-compiled-bindings-xbind-why-do-i-have-to-call-bindings-update

Comment: @Thomas What a coincidence for the same-minute answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out x:Bind defaults to `Mode=OneTime` - I mistakenly thought it's `Mode=OneWay`.
So this does actually work:

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsUnlocked, Mode=OneWay}>
```