# Data Binding does not Update on Property Change (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I am developing an application using c# and the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and am struggling with creating a one-way data-bind between a layout control and an observable class.  Currently, when the observable class property is changed, it does not update the UI element.  I think it has something to do with the fact that I am binding a DataTemplate ListViewItem rather than a static layout element, but I am not sure if this is the problem or how to solve it.  Any help would be appreciated.  The code for the UI element and backend code is shown.

DataTemplate (XAML) (Styling is removed for readability)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="variableTemplate"
              x:DataType="local:VariableNode">
    <Border>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Border>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Button Tag="{Binding Description}"/>
                        <Button Tag="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Grid Margin="0, 10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border >
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <Button Click="Choose_Measurement"
                                Tag="{Binding}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Measurement_Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                           Foreground="{x:Bind MF}" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{x:Bind MF}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button Foreground="{Binding UF}"
                            Tag="{Binding}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding Unit_Exists}"
                            Click="Choose_Unit">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=Unit_Name, Mode=OneWay}"
                                       Foreground="{Binding UF}" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding UF}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

C# Observable Class VariableNode  (Irrelevant properties removed)

```
public class VariableNode : ExperimentNode
{
    public VariableNode() { }
    public VariableNode(VariableType type)
    {
        Type = type;
        Name = name_ref[(int)Type];
        Category = "Problem";
        Unit = -1;
    }

    private string[] name_ref = { "Independent Variable", "Dependent Variable", "Controlled Variable" };
    public enum VariableType { Independent, Dependent, Controlled };
    public VariableType Type { get; set; }
    public Measurement Measure { get; set; }
    public int Unit { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public Measurement MeasureSource
    {
        get { return this.Measure; }
        set
        {
            this.Measure = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Measurement_Name");
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public string Measurement_Name
    {
        get
        {
            if (Measure == null) { return "Select a Measurement"; }
            else { return Measure.Name; }
        }
        set
        {
            if (Measure != null)
            {
                Measure.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }                
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public string Unit_Name
    {
        get
        {
            if (Measure == null) { return "No measurement"; }
            else if (Unit < 0) { return "Select a unit"; }
            else { return Measure.Unit[Unit]; }
        }
    }
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public bool Unit_Exists
    {
        get { return Measure != null; }
    }

}
```

C# XAML.CS code calling the property change

```
public void Choose_Measurement (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    Button butt = sender as Button
    VariableNode sel = butt.Tag as VariableNode;
    sel.Measurement_Name = "New Name";
}
```

Again thanks for the help, I know its a lot of code, and I appreciate the help in debugging / learning.

Comment: `(...) binding a DataTemplate ListViewItem rather than a static layout element (...)` This should not be the issue. Are the other Bindings displayed (for example `{Binding Description}`)? Have You tried switching `x:Bind` with `Binding` (see here why this could matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070705/with-compiled-bindings-xbind-why-do-i-have-to-call-bindings-update)

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so I ended up finding the answer, and I think that it may help others trying to replicate what I am trying to do:

Basically, the class that one is trying to make observable must extend the class `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  So, I ended up making a base class from which to extend all of my observable classes from:

```
public class BaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```