# UWP ListView change Selection mode dynamically

Tags: windows, listview, uwp, win-universal-app, multipleselection

I was wondering if there is a way to change the selection mode of a list view from single to multiple and vice versa from the press of a button.  I have tried binding to the ListView selection mode but this is not working.  Maybe I am doing something wrong.

```
<ListView SelectionMode="{x:Bind SelectionMode}"/>
```

In my on click button code:

```
if (MultipleSelectionModeEnabled)
{
     SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
}
else 
{
     SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Single;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x:Bind` is a compile time binding. i.e, All compilation is completed before rendering. So if you want to force your changes, you need to call `Bindings.Update()`after the property is updated.

Take a look at the explanation about this on the [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33092448/4585476) Here.

So Change your code like this

```
if (MultipleSelectionModeEnabled)
{
     SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
}
else 
{
     SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Single;
}
Bindings.Update();
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 4):

If you do everything right (cannot tell because I don't see the whole code), then adding `Mode=OneWay` to the `x:Bind` expression should help, because the default mode of `x:Bind` is `OneTime`.

```
<ListView SelectionMode="{x:Bind SelectionMode, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```